# Help with translating this quote

Tags: translation, word-choice

I'm going to say a word on peace,  participating in contest at university,  and I have literally no one to check what I've written, and it's tomorrow.
I think of putting this quote from Ibn El Romi:

> Out beyond the ideas of wrongdoing and rightdoing there is a field. I'll meet you there.
>
> Ibn El Romi からの有名引用いんようは "
> 直訳は、
> 間違った行ないと正しい行ないを超えたところに野原が広がっています。そこで逢いましょう

意訳は、

私達の（凝り固まった）固定観念で（物事や相手の）善悪を判断しないで下さい。
その善悪（の決め付け）を超えた所（field）で、私はあなた達に出逢うでしょう。

右も左も超えた所で、私達は出会うでしょう〜

So do you think the translation and grammar is right?

And to share with you the rest of it, if you have any comment I would be grateful to know,

> 平和を目指すためには、どちらかが強制したり無視したりしてはいけません。話し合い、許し合って、前へ進まなければなりません。

And i think of adding the phrase live and let live, would it be 生きて生きる?

About Rumi's quote, ithink from comments thats a little not clear or わかりやすい、so i'm thinking of not saying it at all. What do you think?

Comment: 平和に踏み出す doesn't make sense to me. What were you originally trying to say?

Comment: This is irrelevant if you have other guidelines, but I would note that for a competition speech (which I assume is somewhat formal), it might be preferable/advisable for the speech to be delivered in ます・です style?

Comment: It means that shall we ignore the wrong and right, good and evil and move on behind them there is a field, this meant by peace with other, like you dont have to judge each other,

Comment: 平和に踏み出す= 前へ進まない。

Answer (score 0):

意訳 : 私達{わたしたち}の（凝{こ}り固{かた}まった）固定観念{こていかんねん}で（物事{ものごと}や相手{あいて}の）善悪{ぜんあく}を判断{はんだん}しないで下{くだ}さい。 その善悪{ぜんあく}（の決{き}め付{つ}け）を超{こ}えた所{ところ}（field）で、私{わたし}はあなた達{たち}に出逢{であ}うでしょう。

Your super translation is more easier to understand than direct translation.

> 平和を目指すためには、どちらかが強制したり無視したりしてはいけません。話し合い、許し合って、前へ進まなければなりません。

Is there any original sentence related to this? Grammatically, semantically the sentence seems understandable though.